# consume events in the right order

Tags: javascript, laravel, events, pusher, pusher-js

Im using channel's of pusher in a Laravel application.
So when im fired an event from my controller this is received to my client, and with the pusher function I add some text with this lib https://github.com/albburtsev/jquery.typist on my front page:

```
channel.bind('App\\Events\\TextAdded', function(data) {
            if(data.txt){
                printPhrase(data.txt);
                i++;
            }
        });
        function printPhrase(txt) {
            $('<span>')
                    .addClass('txt_' + i)
                    .appendTo('.typist_dialog')
                    .typist({
                        text:txt,
                        speed: 15,

                    }).on('end_type.typist', function() {
console.log('end')    ;
            }).typistStop() ;
        }

    });
```

As you can see I can catch the event "end_type" (when the function stop writing).

The problem is that i cannot -or I've no idea howto- puts "channel.bind" on queue, and so waiting untill that the `printPhrase(txt)` is finished... so not showing more than one printing for time at screen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to set up some sort of queue to make sure they don't fire until the previous one is done.  This code isn't tested but should do the trick:

```
var printQueue = [];
var queueWorking = false;

channel.bind('App\\Events\\TextAdded', function(data) {
    if(data.txt){
        printQueue.push(data.txt);
        workQueue();
    }
});

function printPhrase(txt) {
    i++;
    $('<span>')
        .addClass('txt_' + i)
        .appendTo('.typist_dialog')
        .typist({
            text:txt,
            speed: 15,
        }).on('end_type.typist', function() {
            queueWorking = false;
            workQueue();
        }).typistStop() ;
    }

function workQueue(){
    if(printQueue.length && !queueWorking){
        queueWorking = true;
        printPhrase(printQueue.shift());
    }
}
```

Comment: great workaround! ill try it asap and ill let you know...i wondering if there is some more function straight from pusher js api...